# SAPUI5 - EventBus

Tags: sapui5

Can any help me with this example?

I'm trying to pass data from one view to another, i've seen in other post that the best practices to do that is using EventBus and i've finded some examples but is not working for me.

Here is my code:

HomeController:

Here i have the documents and once one of these are clicked i want to navigate to other view passing the object.

```
onInit: function(){
    var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    eventBus.publish("Home", "HomeEvent", { text : "Message From Home"});
},
onPressButton: function(oEvent){
    this.getRouter().navTo("view2");
}
```

View2Controller

Here i want to subscribe to the EventBus to get the object that i have passed earlier to get the data object

```
onInit: function(){

},
onPressButton: function(channel, event, data){
    var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    eventBus.subscribe("Home", "HomeEvent", this.showMessage, this);
},
showMessage: function(sChannel, sEvent, oData){
    var msg = oData.text;
    MessageToast.show(msg);
},
onNavBack: function () {
    return BaseController.prototype.onNavBack();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to pass only an ID? Usually in that case you don't need event bus. instead you can pass parameters in your route. Event bus is not well used in UI5 as it was in the past. If you read something from 2015, 2016 don't imagine that it's still true.

Comment: also most data can be passed with the help of models

Answer (score 2):

consider you have two views v1 and v2

You need to call a **function** in v2 before you navigate to v2

Then you write an event bus publish event in v1

Write code below in any event where you want to call some function in v2 before navigating

```
var a = { context: *YourJSONData*, viewName:'xyz'}; //here context and view name are passed as params in the function

sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("app", "**uniquename**", a);
```

Then you write the subscribe event on v2

```
onInit : function () {
        // subscribe to refresh detail tab
        var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
        bus.subscribe("app", "**uniquename**", this.**YourFunctionName**, this);        
    },

**YourFunctionName**:function(channelId, eventId, data) {{
        //Write you code in function as needed data will have whatever you passed
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

**Master-View:**

```
// if not defined on Base Controller..
getEventBus : function() {
    return sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
},

//Time of subscription
onInit : function() {
     var oEventBus = this.getEventBus();
     oEventBus.subscribe("DetailView", "Binded", this.onDetailBinded, this);
}

 //Method if eventbus registers a "publish" command
onDetailBinded : function(){
      // do your thing in MasterView with event bus executed from DetailView
},
```

**Detail-View:**

```
getEventBus : function() {
     return sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
},
             
//Publish event
// e.g. on Button Press or whatever action your want to trigger
YourCallingMethod : function() { 
      var oEventBus = this.getEventBus();
      oEventBus.publish("DetailView", "Binded");
}
```

Comment: btw. master and detail could be used as synonyms for View1 and View2...